# Get last csv-file from dictionary in python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a script that makes figures from csv-files in a specific path. The csv-files are numbered like: session-9995, session-9996 etc. until session-9999.
So my script is searching for those files in the right path, loads in the data and plot the values against time.
The problem is that i have reached session-10000. At some reason python thinks that this session is the first session instead of the last session, because the sessions will be searched as strings.
My question is: How can I change this, so that if I ask to run the last session, that it takes the right one (so the session-10000)?
The part of the script to load in the data is:

```
dic = {}
client_folders = glob.glob(MAIN_FOLDER + '*')
last_client_session = []
last_session = []
a = []
for client_folder in client_folders:
    save_results_to = client_folder + '/afbeeldingen'
    client = os.path.split(client_folder)[-1]
    if client not in CLIENTS_TO_PROCESS and CLIENTS_TO_PROCESS:
        continue
    last_client_session.append(glob.glob(client_folder + '/Sessies/*.csv')[-1]) 
    dic[client_folder] = last_client_session[-1]
```

So the 'last_client_session' need to be session-10000 instead of session-9999. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If you can avoid the problem at the source, make sure files are named `session-09999.csv` etc (or prepend even more zeros). But that's probably not an option.

Comment: Do you make a single plot for each CSV file? And is that all you need the CSV file for, for a single plot?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the ordering of glob, I would suggest creating a little routine to find the filename with the highest number in it. A quick sample function to use could be:

```
def get_last_file (names):
    numbers = [int(name.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]) for name in names]
    max_ix = numbers.index(max(numbers))
    return names[max_ix]

# Test the function
files = ['file-'+str(n) +'.csv' for n in range(1000, 10002)]
print(get_last_file(files))
```

Something like this could then be used for your `last_client_session.append` line:

```
files = glob.glob(client_folder + '/Sessies/*.csv')
last_client_session.append(get_last_file(files))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this script:

```
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(current_dir) if f.endswith(".csv")]
print(f"{files = }")
ids = [int(f.replace("session-", "").replace(".csv", "")) for f in files]
print(f"{ids = }")
paths = [os.path.join(current_dir, f) for f in [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ids, files))]]
print(f"{paths = }")
last_file = paths[-1]
print(f"{last_file = }")
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/test.py
files = ['session-9999.csv', 'session-10000.csv']
ids = [9999, 10000]
paths = ['/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/session-9999.csv', '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/session-10000.csv']
last_file = '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/session-10000.csv'
```

It sorts all files by ids then you take the last file of the list. You just have to open it by it's full path.

Here is the files organisation:

```
/home/vince/stackoverflow
    |test.py
    |session-9999.csv
    |session-10000.csv
```

Comment: Thankyou, This is working correctly!

Comment: You can upvote and greencheck if it answer your question :)